# Get value from first record in group in aggregate query

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

Consider the following laughably simplified *Expenses* database table:

```
|------------------|--------------|--------|
|       Name       | Description  | Amount |
|------------------|--------------|--------|
|    John Smith    |    Hotel     |  £100  |
|    John Smith    | Evening meal |   £30  |
|   Claire Jones   |    Lunch     |   £20  |
|    John Smith    |    Travel    |   £80  |
|   Claire Jones   |    Hotel     |  £150  |
|------------------|--------------|--------|
```

Using the SQL

```
SELECT [Name], SUM([Amount])
FROM [dbo].[Expenses]
GROUP BY [Name]
```

I can get the results

```
|------------------|--------|
|    John Smith    |  £210  |
|   Claire Jones   |  £170  |
|------------------|--------|
```

However, I'm wondering how I can get the same results but with an additional *Description* column which just shows the value from the *Description* column of the base table for the first record in the aggregated group. For example:

```
|------------------|--------------|--------|
|       Name       | Description  | Amount |
|------------------|--------------|--------|
|    John Smith    |    Hotel     |  £210  |
|   Claire Jones   |    Lunch     |  £170  |
|------------------|--------------|--------|
```

This is obviously not the actual data I'm working with, but I'm wondering if it's possible to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such thing as a *first* record, because SQL tables represent *unordered* data.

So, you can use the ordering within a column.  In your case, that might be:

```
SELECT Name, MIN(Description), SUM(Amount)
FROM dbo.Expenses
GROUP BY Name;
```

If you have an ordering column, then you can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT Name, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN Description END),
       SUM(Amount)
FROM (SELECT e.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY ?) as seqnum
      FROM dbo.Expenses e
     ) e
GROUP BY Name;
```

The `?` is a placeholder for the ordering column.

There is another rather arcane way using `FIRST_VALUE()`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name,
       FIRST_VALUE(Description) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY ?), 
       SUM(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY name)
FROM dbo.Expenses;
```

This uses `FIRST_VALUE()` which is available as an analytic function, but not a window function.

Answer (score 2):

Use `subquery` :

```
SELECT [Name], SUM([Amount]) Amount,
       (SELECT TOP 1 Description  
        FROM [dbo].[Expenses] 
        WHERE Name = e.Name 
        ORDER BY Name) Description
FROM [dbo].[Expenses] e
GROUP BY [Name]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use window functions -

```
SELECT [Name],
    SUM([Amount]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Name]) as total_amount,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Name] ORDER BY some_column) as row_num
  FROM [dbo].[Expenses]
  WHERE row_num = 1
```